# How to add a binding programmatically for a NSTabView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings, nstabview

My application contains an `NSTabView` with two tabs. Further, the application itself has a `playState` which is an enum. The `playState` is kept in a *Singleton*.

```
typedef enum {
    kMyAppPlayStatePlaying,
    kMyAppPlayStatePaused
} MyAppPlayState;
```

The `playState` gets synthesized here.

```
@property (readwrite) MyAppPlayState playState;
```

I want to switch the `NSTabView` every time the `playState` changes. Therefore, I prepared an `IBOutlet` to add a binding similar to this one.

```
[self.playPauseTabView bind:@"selectedItemIdentifier" toObject:[MyAppState sharedState] withKeyPath:@"playState" options:nil];
```

I already recognized the `identifier` must be `NSString`. This does not match with my enum which is an `int`. I could maybe use an `NSValueTransformer` to fix this.
Further, `selectedItemIdentifier` does not exists. `NSTabView` only offers `selectedTabViewItem` which then allows to access `identifier` or `label`. Though, I cannot find a way to switch the item itself based on the identifer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like that, I find myself doing one of two things:

1) Register self (or some other object) as an observer of the property in question, and set the selected tab accordingly in `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`. It could look like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{ 
    if ( context == PlayStateChange )
    {
        if ( [[change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeKindKey] integerValue] == NSKeyValueChangeSetting )
        {
            NSNumber *oldValue = [change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
            NSNumber *newValue = [change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

            NSInteger oldInteger = [oldValue integerValue];
            NSInteger newInteger = [newValue integerValue];

            NSLog(@"Old play state: %ld, new play state: %ld", (long)oldInteger, (long)newInteger);

            // Do something useful with the integers here
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

2) declare a readonly NSString * property and declare that its value is affected by your `playState` property. Something like this:

```
@property (readonly) NSString *playStateStr;

// Accessor
-(NSString *)playStateStr
{
    return playState == kMyAppPlayStatePlaying ? @"playing" : "paused";
}

+(NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingPlayStateStr
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject: @"playState"];
}
```

Now you have an NSString-typed property that you can bind your tab view's selection.

Comment: 1) As I understand, that means I add `[[MyAppState sharedState] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playState" options:NSKeyValueChangeSetting context:nil];`. But can I then retrieve the current state from `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`?

Comment: Yes, it will be in the change dictionary with the key `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey`. Being an integer, it should be wrapped in an NSNumber. Notice the "should", haven't checked - I always use strings for this sort of thing.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. You wrote that you "doing one of two things". That means both pratices are independent from each other, right? So how can I retrieve the state value from `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`? Can you add an example please?

Comment: Very cool. I got rid of the `NSValueTransformer` and everything works fine with 2 small methods: `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` and `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to connect the `NSTabView` with its `IBOutlet` in the Interface Builder.
The following works for me.

```
NSDictionary* playStateOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[[PlayStateValueTransformer alloc] init] forKey:NSValueTransformerBindingOption];
[self.playPauseTabView bind:@"selectedLabel" toObject:[MyAppState sharedState] withKeyPath:@"playState" options:playStateOptions];
```

In the `NSValueTransformer` I return an `NSString` which must be set in Interface Builder for each tab!